# Find out how and who hacked into personal Facebook account

Tags: facebook, user-accounts, hacked

Someone tagged photos of a guy I date and myself to the guy's friends (a woman) wall, but kept the guy blocked from seeing pictures. I did not do this but the guy showed me the girl's wall and my name and profile pic is assigned to this thread:

`www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid=118836281628587&set=a.118836261628589.19601.100005066 theater`.

I tried to break number code apart (what is user id vs photo id vs app id) I am not a computer tech person. I just want to clear my name with guy and find out who broke into my account and caused havoc. This photo referenced I never had in my possession too. Also is there a way to get the hackers ip address. They either made a fake profile or bypassed password (token?) Because I never had to change password after.

Comment: You should contact Facebook and tell them you believe your account has been hacked. The help pages for hacked accounts are here: https://www.facebook.com/help/131719720300233/

Comment: Thanks but that "hacked" section you referred me to wasn't very helpful. I already posted this exact post on facebook developers web section and they referred me to web applications. What I am mainly looking for is someone to decipher this "www.facebook.com?php" text code. User I'd is where. What is a fixed number on this code? I look for certain number of characters but don't know facebook computer language. Thanks for your help. K

Answer (score 3):

There isn't anything to crack it's just the link to the photo from the profile (`http://www.facebook.com/kimberly.schmitt.14`) if that's your profile then it's from your account. If it's not for example your profile is http://www.facebook.com/kimberly.schmitt then someone made a fake account so you should report it.

The photo link can be broken down as follows

`http://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid=118836281628587&set=a.118836261628589.19601.100005066474445&type=3&theater`

fbid=[118836281628587](http://facebook.com/118836281628587) photo object id of the particular photo
[118836261628589](http://facebook.com/118836261628589) album object id that the photo is in
[100005066474445](http://facebook.com/100005066474445) profile/account that the album is from

Answer (score 1):

Under your [Security Settings](https://www.facebook.com/settings?tab=security) you can expand the Active Sessions row at the bottom of the list to see the locations your account has been accessed from. If you hover over the location, a tooltip should appear with the IP address that it was accessed from.

Comment: That active sessions didn't help me. Probably because I always check this and delete if I am on my blackberry, pc. Can you decipher this php code for me. As I asked above, where is the fixed number code within above string? This could help me deduce all misc individual photo ident numbers album ident #s or tokens etc. Thanks for your help! :) K